# SQL Distinct Count and Case when

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Here is my query for Microsoft SQL Server:

```
select count(distinct AEN) as Customers  
from 
(   select top 100 ERDAT, AEN,  
    case 
        when AEN = 'MBLE' AND ERDAT between '20220401' and '20220430' then 'Mobile'
        when AEN = 'ISU' AND ERDAT between '20220401' and '20220430' then 'Website'
        when AEN = 'CRM' AND ERDAT between '20220401' and '20220430' then 'CRM'
        when AEN like '_[0-9]%' AND ERDAT between '20220401' and '20220430' then 'ID Number'
        else 'Others'
    end as 'Channels' 
    from [Table]
)
```

Apparently there is issues with the brackets. Any help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: What is the error? I think you sneed an alias : `... from [Table]) t`.

Comment: mysql or (ms)sql-server? Please remove irrelevant tags

Comment: If you have a syntax error publish it in full if the outcome is not as desired state the problem you are trying to solve and how your solution falls short. I have removed the mysql tag since this appears to be a sql-server question.

Comment: Please provide example data

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, you need an alias for your subquery.

change this

```
count(distinct AEN) as Customers
```

into this

```
count(distinct t.AEN) as Customers
```

and also this

```
    [table]
)
```

into this

```
    [table]
) t
```

look at this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=28ec21c5515bacf8dadc5c2ad645882e)

This will run without the error, but I have no clue if this is what you want to achieve, your question is not any clear about that